# Is it currently possible to convert ssdlite mobilenet v2 as a tflite model?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I tried to transform my already trained model using toco, following the guidelines described in the g3doc. I tested the model on pc and it runs well but after conversion the model seems to be outputting random values on android. I converted is as a float model. Is it currently even possible to transform said model to a tflite format or is the only model currently supported by toco for object detection only ssd mobilenet v1 ?

I also did test the "serve tflite model in 30 min" tutorial and it worked there (also using their dockerfiles)

Comment: also the class node is giving me negative decimal values, so it's not just bad prediction

Comment: Did you get it running correctly?

Comment: somewhat, I used the pipeline config from the samples directory. It still gives negative values sometimes but you can filter it out and it sorta works then.